# CSS dotted border issue in adjacent columns in a table rendered as dash in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, border

When I run this code http://jsfiddle.net/KW3Dw/4/ in Chrome and Firefox, both display border differently. I see a dash in between adjacent cells in Chrome, while in Firefox, it's rendered without any dashes. How can i fix this?

Comment: if the width of the first cell makes the border end in a dot, and the next cell's border starts with a dot it shows a "dash", which are 2 dots next to each other. You can force the first cell's width to match an uneven times the width of one dot so it always ends in no-dot. Make the first td `width:40px` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Bazzz i applied width to 40px, but i don't see any change.

Comment: @varunvs, See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6250394/632951

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set horizontal border-spacing to even number of pixels between cells and between border's dots.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gmhuw/

You can't "fix" it by modifying your table's style, these dots are interpreted that way by Chrome. That's just the browser's limiation.

Comment: What has the `border-spacing` got to do with the solution?

Comment: one or two more pixels can makes a difference

Comment: This works relatively well, however if you also have a background colour per row, then these are pulled apart per cell, leaving a clear gap in between.