# CSS dotted border render issue

Tags: css, border

I'm seeing a rendering issue for a 2px dotted border similar to [CSS dotted border issue in adjacent columns in a table rendered as dash in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941640/css-dotted-border-issue-in-adjacent-columns-in-a-table-rendered-as-dash-in-chrom) but on desktop Safari and Chrome. I tried several widths and it happens in all of them

This is a sample:

[image: sample]

the vertical line ending has the same issue but it's out of the picture.

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/bcdQQ/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue happens if the width is not divisible by the border-width.

This works:
http://jsfiddle.net/bcdQQ/5/ (i made it a little bit bigger, for better sight)

```
#prodpre { 
    border-bottom: #555 5px dotted;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    width: 505px;
}
```

So, the only possibility to catch this issue, would be a javascript solution, which corrects the width of the div, so it is divisible by the border-width (cause it is dynamically in your example).

Comment: I tried your fiddle, tries 500px with, 10px dot and in chrome and safari get the same issue

Comment: I try it but got the same issue in iPhone and iPad

Answer (score 0):

could you put it in a smaller container div with overflow hidden?

Comment: it may solve some issues but it would be tricky to apply that some times