# How to avoid borders from collapsing

Tags: html, css, border

This is a question keeping me busy for a while now.

As you can see in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35qgP/1/) I'm trying to set a border to the top of the cells.
I want to achieve that the borders of the cells look like the border I gave the div.
Have you got any idea how to do it? I already tried to set a border-image, but it wouldn't work, too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS dotted border render issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822810/css-dotted-border-render-issue)

Comment: The question is not really about border collapse. It’s about rendering borders in a table at cell corners, and this is well covered in an older question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying this is what you are expecting: http://jsfiddle.net/35qgP/4/

```
table {
    width: 50%;
}
.border1 td {
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}
.border2 td {
    border-top: 1px dotted blue;
}
.border3 td {
    border-top: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

Or use a `border-collapse: collapse;` for all the `td`s this way:

```
td {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. As you can see the blue dots are doubled when the cell-borders are crossing.

Comment: There are no crossing borders. And there is no border collapse, as there are no adjacent borders.

Comment: Hi...thanks for the information. Post it as an answer and I'll markt it as solved. I created a workaround though ;-)

Comment: @user1437032 Done with teh adding `border-collapse: collapse;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

http://jsfiddle.net/35qgP/2/

Comment: Hi, the number of px does not matter. It's more that the blue dots are  doubled. The eye catches the irregularity.