# How to control length of the dash to the border without using image with css only?

Tags: css

I need to change the length of the dash in a border bottom. I want to make the length of each dash 30px. Is there any chance to do this without using any images?

Comment: this you can not do in pure css, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250394/how-to-increase-space-between-dotted-border-dots/6250467#6250467

Comment: no, the length of the dash can't be fine-tuned.

Answer (score 7):

Without *any* images it's impossible. But it can be done without *loading* any images — with CSS gradients (which are basically generated images):

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, currentColor 0%, currentColor 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%) repeat-x left bottom;    
background-size: 60px 1px;
```

Comment: that's a cool idea ... similarly, for more sophisticated patterns without loading external images you could also use data-uri backgrounds in the css.