# CSS dashed paragraph

Tags: css, underline

Hello is it possible to control how many dashed lines would be under the word?

I have something like this:

```
<p>Duza</p>

p {
  border-bottom: 4px dashed #999;
  display: inline;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

And the effect that I want to have:[image]

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2eLb175/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control the length of CSS dashes or the space between them. ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421927/how-to-control-length-of-the-dash-to-the-border-without-using-image-with-css-onl) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250394/how-to-increase-space-between-dotted-border-dots))

Solutions could be:

- Use more than one word to allow room for the dashes
- Use `dotted` rather than `dashed`
- as the links above point out, you could possibly use a gradient or an image

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/k2eLb175/1/)