# Change dash length (Dashed Border CSS / SCSS)

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div with a border that runs around all sides.

I want to transform from solid to dashed on hover. However I want to control the length on the dashes.

I understand that this may be possible with SCSS?

Comment: have you tried border-image:?

Comment: Why would you think Sass could control the length of the dashes?  The only thing Sass can do is compile to CSS.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250394/how-to-increase-space-between-dotted-border-dots

Comment: Yeah I did, but the transition is terrible.

Comment: I came across this so was wondering whether it would be possible to do it for all sides: http://thephuse.com/development/customizing-your-dashed-and-dotted-borders-in-css3/

Comment: There were no suitable answers in the older question linked for the tools available now. After a crash course in the `border-image` property, [I have provided an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26858151/2930477) so you can roll your own border :)

Comment: @user2307186 - you could fade a border over the top on hover, [like in this example](http://jsbin.com/hepimu/2/edit) to give a smoother transition using opacity.

Comment: @misterManSam I was experimenting with this but couldn't quite get it to look how I wanted when it was applied to my box. I ended up resorting to using a background image and another div placed over the top that had the original line border for transition. They then work in parallel on hover creating as best transition as I want.