# Border with custom dash length and spacing

Tags: html, css

How can I achive this kind of border? This 20px dash and 20px spacing between dashes. Is it even possible without custom background file? The closest i can get is something like this:

```css
   .element {
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
      border-radius: 45px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, white 50%);
      background-position: top;
      background-size: 10px 1px;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
```

```html
 
    
    <div class="element">
    TEXT TEXT
    </div>
```

live: https://jsfiddle.net/roo5rbb3/

[image]

Comment: This answer works best. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40054141/6358350

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
border-style: dashed;
```

So your complete css will look like this:

```
.element {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, white 50%);
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 10px 1px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
```