# Single line border-image

Tags: html, css

I have a PNG which is 10px x 1px and I need to use it for a border-image but for some reason the image doesn't repeat. It appears in the corners but not all the way? What am I doing wrong?

```css
#border {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed transparent;
  border-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/byABRJ/border.png) 1 100% repeat;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
  bordered area
</div>
```

Comment: can you use an absolute path so we  can see the image with you

Comment: so how we can help ? :)

Comment: I have uploaded the image to ImgBB ...

Comment: I see no image....

Comment: Done now - fully linked/working

Comment: Without further info of the desired result, you can simply use border/outline: ?px dashed #?;

Comment: Indeed but the dash is unfortunately different ...

Answer (score 2):

Wrong start, it's 0 not 100

```
  border-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/byABRJ/border.png) 1 0% repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you set to 100% is `border-image-width`, I think you want it to be 1 (or you can omit it, I think it's 1 by default).

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <style>
    #border {
     width:200px;
     height:100px;
     border:1px dashed transparent;
     border-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/byABRJ/border.png) 1 1 repeat;
     background:yellow;
     text-align:center;
     line-height:100px;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="border">
    bordered area
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

EDIT: If you want your border-image to be the same on the left/right edges you'll have to add those to the source image you're using. Take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Comment: Can it also do the edges or do I need different code for that?

Comment: Edited my answer to include a link for that

Comment: An easy step by step guide can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771171/control-the-dashed-border-stroke-length-and-distance-between-strokes

Comment: If you want to go down the easy road (with less control), just use `border: 1px dashed #666;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way.

```css
#border {
   width:200px;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   height:100px;
   border-top:1px dashed blue;
   border-bottom:1px dashed blue;
   background:yellow;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <div id="border">
        bordered area
       </div>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end building an image which CSS then used for the border proved too time consuming. Instead I found:

[How to increase space between dotted border dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250394/how-to-increase-space-between-dotted-border-dots/50368553#50368553)

And have posted an answer with my solution there. Although not a direct-fix to the presented question it solves it and without images which for me was easier.