# Border dashed spacing on Css

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
display: flex;
padding: 1rem;
border-radius: 4px;
justify-content: space-between;
margin-bottom: .8rem;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
min-height: 51px;
border: 1px dashed #DFDFDF;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

I need the space to be like in the picture and the width

[image]

Comment: you have to use SVG for this, example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9m6axmry/

Comment: you can't change the length of the dashes and spaces, but you might be able to sort it out with [border images](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_border_images.asp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase space between dotted border dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250394/how-to-increase-space-between-dotted-border-dots)