# Increase length of dots on border

Tags: html, css, input, border

I am using an input in one of my projects and I'm making a dotted line on the bottom. Ideally, I would like to have about 5 dots about 10px wide each. Kind of like the example below:
 `________  ________ _______ ______ _____`.

This is the code that I have so far :

```css
input {
  border-bottom: 3px tomato dotted;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" numbers-only>
```

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez there is a code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use gradient

```css
input {
  border-bottom: 3px solid tomato;
  border-bottom:none;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,tomato 0 10px,transparent 0 15px) bottom/100% 3px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" numbers-only/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a background with linear-gradient to get 5 lines like this:

```css
input {
  border-bottom: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 90%, white 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 40px 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" numbers-only />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to change the default styling of the `dotted` border type.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064496/14956277) uses the `background-image` property with a gradient to simulate a border.

You can use this trick on an element behind your input like the following example.

```css
#my-input {
  /* Keep form compatability by
     using an inline display type */
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* Make some space at the bottom
     for the gradient to show under
     the input */
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, tomato 50%, transparent 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 20px 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#my-input input {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```